# Switch power below 3.7V

Tags: power-supply, transistors, mosfet

I use ESPHome to measure temperature, power the solar system and an additional battery only for ESPhome. The charging modul controls the charging of the battery, everything works until the battery voltage drops, after which the ESPHome will no longer turn on when the voltage comes from the solar system.

I would like to install a transistor or MOSFET switch that is connected to the ESPHome and turns off the power when the voltage drops below 4V - 3.7V.

The relay option does not suit me because of the power consumption, a MOSFET can be used, but it leaks voltage when the battery power is below 3.7v, which I do not want because it is not suitable for ESPhome.

I am looking for a solution to turn off the power supply below 4V - 3.7V so that it does not conduct voltage and turn it on above the set voltage.

I'm asking for advice.

Comment: Maybe you search for a "load switch", "voltage supervisor", "brown out detector". Those are available for exactly that: monitor voltage, if too low, switch the load of or handle the reset pin. If it rises enough, switch it on again. There are parts that only handle reset (e.g. TLV840).

Comment: why do you mean by a mosfet "leaks voltage"? I've never seen that issue. You might not be using the right gate driver. Look into photovoltaic gate drivers if you need high-side (P-chan) switching. You can also look into latching relays, which only need power for a few dozen milliseconds to change and hold state. Lastly, there's cheap dedicated modules for battery management that have under-voltage protection, look for one based around the ubiquitous tp5100.

Comment: By leakage voltage, I meant that the mosfet is still working and there is no voltage at the gate, since the control and output voltage is the same, the gate is connected via a diode.

I'm going to get the TP5100 to try, looks like it should be a ready solution for my situation.

Thank you.